# Broadcast Receiver in a View Pager Adapter

Tags: android

I have an activity which has a view pager in it. I want to update one page of the pager from a broadcast. So, I created a broadcast receiver in my pager adapter. But it is not receiving the broadcast. Is it has something to do with its declaration in manifest.xml(as it is not in some activity)? Is it even possible to do so?
Here is my work in pager adapter:

```
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    try {
        searchBox = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.searchBox);
        searchButton = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
        if (position == 0) {
            v1 = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search, null);
            listOfSearch = (GridView) v1.findViewById(R.id.list_search);
            searchImage = (ImageView) v1.findViewById(R.id.searchImage);
            prb = (ProgressBar) v1.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
            errorMessage = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.errorMsg);
            searchImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    searchBox.requestFocus();
                    imm.showSoftInput(searchBox,
                            InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                }
            });
            searchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchBox.getWindowToken(),
                            0);
                    errorMessage.setText("");
                    searchImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    searchButton.setOnClickListener(null);
                    listOfSearch.setAdapter(null);
                    prb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    new getVideos().execute();
                }
            });
        }
        if (position == 1) {
            receiverl = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    if (intent.getExtras().getInt("running") == 1) {
                        int progress = intent.getExtras()
                                .getInt("progress");
                        DownloadView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        dName.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("name"));
                        pBar.setProgress(intent.getExtras().getInt(
                                "progress"));
                        dPercentage.setText(progress + " %");
                        dQueue.setText("In queue: "
                                + intent.getExtras().getInt("queue"));
                        if (progress >= 100) {
                            apg.setInDownload(false);
                            DownloadView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            getSD();
                            vla = new ViewListAdapter(activity, list,
                                    list2, list3, send);
                            listOfDownloads.setAdapter(vla);
                        }
                    } else {
                        DownloadView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            };
            v1 = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_downloads, null);
            DownloadView = (FrameLayout) v1.findViewById(R.id.downloadView);
            dName = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.nam);
            pBar = (ProgressBar) v1.findViewById(R.id.pbb);
            dPercentage = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.prcent);
            dQueue = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.queue);
            listOfDownloads = (GridView) v1
                    .findViewById(R.id.list_downloads);
            errorText = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.errorText);
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "Video/VidBoxLite");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdirs();
            }
            getSD();
            if (list == null) {
                errorText.setText("No storage found.");
            } else if (list.length == 0) {
                errorText.setText("No videos found.");
            } else {
                vla = new ViewListAdapter(activity, list, list2, list3,
                        send);
                listOfDownloads.setAdapter(vla);
                vla.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listOfDownloads.setLongClickable(true);
                listOfDownloads
                        .setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
                            public boolean onItemLongClick(
                                    AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                                forP = position;
                                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater
                                        .from(activity);
                                View layout = inflater.inflate(
                                        R.layout.downloaded_video_options,
                                        null);
                                ListView oka = (ListView) layout
                                        .findViewById(R.id.option);
                                ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                        activity,
                                        android.R.layout.select_dialog_item);
                                adp.add("Delete");
                                adp.add("Share");
                                adp.add("Cancel");
                                oka.setAdapter(adp);
                                oka.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onItemClick(
                                            AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                                        if (arg2 == 2)
                                            alertDD.dismiss();
                                        if (arg2 == 1) {
                                            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                                            sendIntent.setType("video/*");
                                            sendIntent
                                                    .setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                            sendIntent.putExtra(
                                                    Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                                                    Uri.parse(list2[forP]));
                                            // startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent));
                                            activity.startActivity(Intent
                                                    .createChooser(
                                                            sendIntent,
                                                            "Share video via:"));
                                            alertDD.dismiss();
                                        }
                                        if (arg2 == 0) {
                                            alertDD.dismiss();
                                            File fle = new File(list2[forP]);
                                            if (fle.exists()) {
                                                fle.delete();
                                                getSD();
                                                if (list == null) {
                                                    errorText
                                                            .setText("No storage found.");
                                                } else if (list.length == 0) {
                                                    errorText
                                                            .setText("No videos found.");
                                                } else {
                                                    vla = new ViewListAdapter(
                                                            activity, list,
                                                            list2, list3,
                                                            send);
                                                    listOfDownloads
                                                            .setAdapter(vla);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                });
                                AlertDialog.Builder alertD = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                        activity);
                                alertD.setView(layout).setCancelable(false);
                                alertDD = alertD.create();
                                alertDD.show();
                                return true;
                            }
                        });
                listOfDownloads
                        .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                    View view, int position, long id) {
                                if (position < send) {
                                    Uri ttt = Uri.parse(Environment
                                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                            + File.separator
                                            + "Video/VidBox/Lite/"
                                            + list[position]);
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                                            Intent.ACTION_VIEW, ttt);

                                    intent.setDataAndType(
                                            ttt,
                                            "video/"
                                                    + list[position]
                                                            .substring(
                                                                    list[position]
                                                                            .length() - 3,
                                                                    list[position]
                                                                            .length()));
                                    activity.startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(v1, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return v1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to register your receiver? You can do it in your manifest file, or by calling
activity.registerReceiver(receiver); method.
U should note that if u are registering it by calling activity.registerReceiver(receiver);
u will also have to unregister it when the receiver is no more required..